# Correct order of integration in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm having troubles with an integral of the following form:

$I=\int\limits_a^\infty dr\, r^2\int\limits_0^\pi d\theta\,\sin(\theta)f(r,\theta)$.

My problem lies in the fact that these integrals are NOT commutative convergent!

If I'd first solve the integral over $r$, I'd get that $I\rightarrow\infty$.

If I'd first solve the integral over $\theta$, I'd get that $I=0$.

Now this integral results from taking a volume-integral in spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\varphi)$, where I got rid of $\varphi$ since the entire function didn't depend on $\varphi$.

My question was if there was a pre-defined order in spherical coordinates? So that I might be able to recognise the right answer.

**edit**
The function $f(r,\theta)$ equals:

$f(r,\theta)=(2\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta))/r.$

Comment: Nope, there is no predefined order. You probably made a mistake. What is $f(r,\theta)$?

Comment: @DavidH added the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're volume integral is improper. The region of integration is the limit of a spherical shell, with an inner radius $a$ to an outer radius $b$, as the outer radius $b\rightarrow\infty$. So you integral is really,

$$I=\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}I(b),\\
\text{where }\,I(b)=\int\limits_a^b dr\, r^2\int\limits_0^\pi d\theta\,\sin(\theta)f(r,\theta).$$

Note the order of integration for $I(b)$ clearly does not matter since the integrand is separable in $r$ and $\theta$, and either way comes to $I(b)=(b-a)\cdot 0=0$.

Hence, $$I=\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}I(b)=\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}0=0.$$

Comment: Thanks, should have indeed spotted that one! I had already set it to 0 since it seemed logic to me since while splitting a prefector (the one of the integral of $\theta$) became zero!